# Write OCR retrieved text from each image to separate text file corresponding to each image

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I am reading a pdf file and converting each page to images and saving the, Next I need to run OCR on each image and identify each image text and write it to a new text file.

I know how to get all text from all images and dump it into one text file.

```
pdf_dir = 'dir path'
os.chdir(pdf_dir)

for pdf_file in os.listdir(pdf_dir):
    if pdf_file.endswith(".pdf"):
        pages = convert_from_path(pdf_file, 300)
        pdf_file = pdf_file[:-4]
        for page in pages:
            page.save("%s-page%d.jpg" % (pdf_file,pages.index(page)), "JPEG") 

img_dir = 'dir path'
os.chdir(img_dir)

docs = []

for img_file in os.listdir(img_dir):
    if img_file.endswith(".jpg"):
        texts = str(((pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(img_file)))))
        text = texts.replace('-\n', '')  
        print(texts)
        img_file = img_file[:-4]
        for text in texts:
            file = img_file + ".txt"
#          create the new file with "w+" as open it
            with open(file, "w+") as f:
                for texts in docs:
                # write each element in my_list to file
                    f.write("%s" % str(texts))
                    print(file)
```

I need one text file to be written corresponding to each image which has recognized the text within that image. The files which are presently written are all empty and I am not sure what is going wrong. Can someone help?

Comment: `docs` is an empty list. also you're using `text` as an iterator within nested loops. maybe not an error but probably not a good practice to make.

Comment: you *probably* just want `with open(file, 'w+') as f:` and then `f.write('%s' % str(text))`.

Comment: Yes, I realized that I am creating an empty list and then iterating over it, so it is leading to empty docs. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's kind of a lot to unpack here:

1. You're iterating over `docs` which is an empty list, to create the text files, so as a result, each text file is merely *created* (empty) and the `file.write` is never executed.
2. You're assigning `text = texts.replace('-\n', '')` but then you're not doing anything with it, instead iterating over `for text in texts` so within *that* loop, `text` is not the result of the `replace` but rather an item from the iterable `texts`.
3. Since `texts` is a `str`, each `text in texts` is a *character*.
4. You're then using `texts` (also previously assigned) as an iterator over `docs` (again, this is empty).

2 and 4 aren't necessarily problematic, but probably are not good practice. 1 seems to be the main culprit for why you're producing empty text files. 3 seems to also be a logical error as you almost certainly do not want to write out individual characters to the file(s).

So I *think* this is what you want, but it is untested:

```
for img_file in os.listdir(img_dir):
    if img_file.endswith(".jpg"):
        texts = str(((pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(img_file)))))
        print(texts)
        file = img_file[:-4] + ".txt"
        #create the new file with "w+" as open it
        with open(file, "w+") as f:
            f.write(texts)
            print(file)
```

Comment: After a li'l trial I arrived to the same corrections in the code, thanks for explaining those four points to me. It helps! thank you!

Comment: Cheers @shweta24. Also I notice that `texts` is already a string, so there's no need to do: `f.write("%s" % str(texts))`, you can do more simply: `f.write(texts)`.

Comment: Yupp, noticed that :). Thanks David !